# Flutter Web updating a Value from a Document in Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Cloud Firestore Database with a List of Songs

[image: Firabase Collection]

I want to update the Document likes, when the user adds a Song with the same Song title
I tried the update Method but it doesnt really work the value does not get updated. I think i can´t really access the Document, maybe my structure in Cloud Firestore is wrong.

```
void _saveLike(Song item) async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .doc('Songs/${item.title}')
        .update({'likes': item.likes}).then((likes) => print('Song updated'));
  }
```

This is my Method to update the value

```
 void checkSong(Song item) {
    bool isSongFound = false;
    list.forEach((s) {
      if (s.title.trim() == item.title.trim()) {
        setState(() {
          s.likes++;
        });
        _saveLike(item);
        
        isSongFound = true;
      }
    });
    if (!isSongFound) {
      addSong(Song(title: textfieldControllersong.text, like: false, likes: 0));
    }
  }
```

This is my Method to check whether the Song already exist or not.

Are there better ways to Structure a List with Cloud Firebase or even other Database Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access a document like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .doc('Songs/${item.title}')
```

The database looks for a document named `item.title` in the `Songs` collection, and no document with that ID exists.

To updated a document based on the value of its field(s), you first need to [run a query](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#querying) to find the document(s), and *then* run the update.

Something like:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('Songs')
  .where('title', isEqualTo: item.title)
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) {
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      doc.reference.update({'likes': item.likes})
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! The code you posted has following error: The getter 'reference' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'. Do i have to create a reference from my collection to access it properly? Sorry if this is a dumb Question

Comment: Yeah, that should've been `doc`. For such errors, I recommend keeping the reference docs handy: 
 https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html